# Интерфейс похожий на диаграмму классов

Tags: delphi, интерфейс, компоненты

*Захотел сделать карту сюжета для своей новеллы, ближайший аналог - карты мыслей, но доступные не соответсвуют моим запросам.
Понравился интерфейс диаграммы классов в делфи и хочу написать чтонибудь подобное.*
нужно Создание текстовых заметок, свободное их перемещение по форме и рисование связей (стрелочек) между ними. Обязательное условие - независимость(возможность отсутсвия связей) заметок друг от друга(что невозможно в "картах мыслей") и это не органайзер(таблица), это именно свободно перемещаемые и создаваемые в любых количествах большие куски текста(RTF) который можно редактировать.
Подскажите в какую сторону гуглить, или может знаете уже готовый проект с похожим функционалом(лучше открытый)?

[image: Стикеры]

Comment: Насчёт готовых не знаю, но компоненты можно создавать вручную. Панелька с тремя кнопками и текстовым редактором.  Компонент линия - можно поискать.

Comment: А как на счет любого онлайн редактора схем?